# Geo Lat/Lng normalize in Javascript

Tags: javascript, geolocation, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

Hello I have the problem that i use leaflet and I dont boundbox the map.
Now if an user is drag the map and going out of the normal -180 to 180 lng or -90 to 90 lat my markers dont shown at the new location.

The marker will requested from an api I have written.
Where I use the boundbox coordinates. The problem now is, that I send something like:

```
lat_min:-23.563987128451217
lat_max:70.61261423801925
lon_min:-343.828125
lon_max:136.40625
```

to my script and I don't know how i can normalize the coordinates correct to pass the degrees.

EDIT 24.10.2016 01:33 UTC

My MySQL use between:

```
geolat: {
  $between: [lat_min, lat_max]
},
geolon: {
  $between: [lon_min, lon_max]
},
```

Thank you for your hints and tips.

Comment: Have you tried map [`worldCopyJump`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#map-worldcopyjump) option?

Comment: Hello @ghybs thank you for this hint, but this works only if i drag over 50% of the mal to one side. But i looking for a function that works like on google where the marker jump to the side thats new when the marker out of the view.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a known limitation of Leaflet. See Leaflet issues [#2506](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/2506) and [#4919](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4919#issuecomment-247741811)

Answer (score 0):

Dude leaflet itself provides `wrapLatLng` which can be used as `map.wrapLatLng(latLngPoint)`, this returns normalized form of latitude longitude how we need.